# Exceed maxComputeWorkGroupCount device limitation in dispatch call

Tags: vulkan

According to the [Vulkan spec document](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/vkCmdDispatch.html) :

> To record a dispatch, call:
>
> void vkCmdDispatch(
>       VkCommandBuffer                             commandBuffer,
>       uint32_t                                    groupCountX,
>       uint32_t                                    groupCountY,
>       uint32_t                                    groupCountZ);
>
> groupCountX must be less than or equal to VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::maxComputeWorkGroupCount[0]

But I have call dispatch with groupCountX bigger than the physical device limit and it works just fine. And the validation layer didn't give any warning about it. I'm just wondering if this WorkGroupCount limitation only applied to certain vendors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,
Valid Usage sections in the Vulkan specifications are absolute.
(except extensions are [sometimes treated poorly](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/533) in current version of the text, but that does not apply to this case)

Violating Valid Usage leads to Undefined Behavior. That means anything from "everything appears to work normally" to "your PC becomes sentient and enslaves humanity".

For all intents and purposes violation of Valid Usage is a logical error of your code and you should not do it, ever.

If it is not reported by the validation layers, make sure you have them enabled correctly and that you are indeed over the limit. Otherwise the layers are incomplete and you should report it at [their repo](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues).

Comment: Oh turns out there's an issue referencing this already : [github issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/2063). But thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

No, we cannot say that the reported limits apply only to certain vendors. Physical device limits acquired through *vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties()* function call apply to the device installed on a computer You execute Your application on. When You create a logical device from such physical device, then parameters used in Your application must be confined to the reported bounds. They are specific to the combination of the hardware/vendor/operating system/driver and may be different if any of these changes. But the specification requires hardware to support some minimal (or maximal) values and these required limits apply to all vendors. For example all vendors must support maxComputeWorkGroupCount that is at least 65535.

As for the first part of Your question - why it works correctly... Well, specification states that if You go beyond limits then You may get undefined behavior. Application that works correctly even if we don't obey the limits can still be perceived as an undefined behavior. So why it works may be not as strange as the question if on given hardware dispatching larger number of groups is still possible, then why the driver reports smaller value of a group count? I don't know the answer and can only speculate. Maybe there are some circumstances (like some state parameters/values or the size of a compute shader, or the number of descriptors accessed in the shader) that lower the number of dispatched workgroups to the reported limit and You just didn't hit it (yet).